# Adding event.preventDefault() Kills SoundJS

Tags: javascript, html, audio, soundjs

I have an existing javascript game I'm trying to add sound to using SoundJS. The problem I'm having is that the line of code that prevents the iphone from dragging the window around when the player moves their finger across the screen is also causing all sounds to not play. If I comment out that single line ("e.preventDefault();"), the sound works perfectly, but the game is unplayable. Has anyone else run into this? Here's the complete function for getting the mouse coordinates:

```
function mouse_move (finger, e)
  {
  if (!e) var e = event;
  if (finger == true) e.preventDefault();

  main_target_x = e.pageX - canvas_html.offsetLeft;
  main_target_y = e.pageY - canvas_html.offsetTop;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

I found a slightly alternate way of preventing the screen dragging, which does not seem to interfere with the sound.  My event handlers:

```
canvas_html.addEventListener   ("mousedown",   function() {mouse_down (false)}, false);
canvas_html.addEventListener   ("mousemove",   function() {mouse_move (false)}, false);
canvas_html.addEventListener   ("touchstart",  function() {mouse_down (true)},  false);
canvas_html.addEventListener   ("touchmove",   function() {mouse_move (true)},  true);
canvas_html.addEventListener   ("touchend",    function() {mouse_up (true)},    false);
document.body.addEventListener ("mouseup",     function() {mouse_up (false)},   false);
document.body.addEventListener ("touchcancel", function() {mouse_up (true)},    false);
document.body.addEventListener ('touchmove',   function (event) {event.preventDefault()}, false);
```

I commented out the "preventDefault" in my mouse_move() function and added a new event handler for 'touchmove' at the end of the list, just to handle the "preventDefault".

This was just a wild guess, and I'm not entirely sure why it works this way and not the other way.  It does, indeed, work, however, and I now have both sound and a stable screen.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your question. I have not seen this behaviour before, and it really does not make sense as SoundJS does not do anything with mouse_move events. My best guess is that the preventDefault is somehow being applied to all events.

If you could toss together a minimal spike that demonstrates this issue in action, I will try to look into it a little further.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, Ojay. Thanks for the reply.

Could you describe what you mean by "minimal spike"? I'm not familiar with the term.

Comment: by minimal spike I mean a small test case with the minimum amount of code required to reproduce the problem.  It makes it a lot easier to solve the problem on our end.